# Websocket connection closed (on mobile browsers) when screen locks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, stompjs

I have a connection to WebSocket which sends me data every second, but when I lock the screen of my phone, after 5 min (approximately), the WebSocket connection gets closed with code 1006.

That only happens when locking the screen. If I open another tab, everything is okay.

Comment: Is it happening only in ios mobiles? I am also facing similar issue but happening only in ios mobles. So, just want to confirm

Answer (score 2):

It happens because a mobile device is locked, goes to sleep or the application is moved to the background, an active WebSocket connection may become unresponsive and not close itself properly.

There is no way you can prevent this behaviour w/o forcing your browser to keep working in the background.

Comment: Is there a possibility to re-establish the websocket connection on opening the browser again after locking the phone?